# PHP: $_POST is Empty on Default Page URL

Tags: php, post, form-submit, is-empty

I have a form that submits to my site with POST parameters:

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>

  <form name="myform" action="http://myserver/mysite" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="param1" value="1">
    <input type="hidden" name="param2" value="2">
    <input type="hidden" name="param3" value="3">
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
  </form>

</body>
</html>
```

In the `mysite` folder I have a default page (`index.php`):

```
<?php var_dump($_POST); ?>
```

The result is empty if the URL of the form is `http://myserver/mysite`. If I change the URL to `http://myserver/mysite/index.php`, then the `$_POST` is filled with the parameters.

What am I supposed to do to get the parameters when the URL is `http://myserver/mysite`?

Comment: Is there any index.html inside the directory `mysite`?

Comment: No there is not. Only index.php and other PHP pages.

Comment: There is no codes in there. Only **var_dump($_POST);**. The source page (with form tag) is **.html**.

Comment: Disable directory listing?

Comment: In index.php, add an echo like `echo 'Form Submission Received.';` Just so you know the file is actually being accessed.

Comment: It is accessible. Because it prints "empty array ...".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just do like this to get $_POST values,

```
<form name="myform" action="http://myserver/mysite/" method="post">
```

Adding the forward slash to the end of action will work.

Comment: @Sajan, WOW! It Works...!! Could you please explain Why?

Comment: I learned something today. (Or maybe got reminded of something I haven't run into in a while.)

Comment: John Croneh , browser url ends with forward slash right ?

Comment: Mmm... So So. Thanks for the tip anyway.

Answer (score 1):

try this...

```
  <form name="myform" action="http://myserver/mysite/" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="param1" value="1">
    <input type="hidden" name="param2" value="2">
    <input type="hidden" name="param3" value="3">
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
  </form>
```

and place following line in .htaccess

```
Options -Indexes
```